# VB6 editor display accented characters all mixed up with the wrong code page

Tags: vb6

In the picture below my VB show those special character instead of ÉÉÉâââ.

[image: VB6 screenshot]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not thought of it at first! If I change the font in the "Editor Format options", it fix my issue.
[image: Tools-Options-Editor Format]